# Oracle - Update with join

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

Using Oracle 11g. I need to do an update with a self join. Oracle doesn't support updates with joins and using MERGE isn't working as I'm trying to do an update on columns used in the on clause

What I've tried:

```
update 
  (
     select  a.ID, a.FROM_STAGE_ID, a.TO_STAGE_ID, b.TO_STAGE_ID 
       from  STATES a,
             STATES b
      where  a.ID = b.ID and
             a.TO_STAGE_ID = b.FROM_STAGE_ID and
             a.TO_STAGE_ID = 'FIZZBUZZ' and
             a.FROM_STAGE_ID <> b.TO_STAGE_ID and
             a.CODE = b.CODE
   )
   set a.TO_STAGE_ID=b.TO_STAGE_ID;
```

This resulted in : "SQL Error: ORA-00904: "B"."TO_STAGE_ID": invalid identifier"

```
 MERGE
   INTO STATES a
  USING STATES b
     ON (  
           a.ID = b.ID and
           a.TO_STAGE_ID = b.FROM_STAGE_ID and
           a.TO_STAGE_ID = 'FIZZBUZZ' and
           a.FROM_STAGE_ID <> b.TO_STAGE_ID and
           a.CODE = b.CODE
         )
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  set a.TO_STAGE_ID = b.TO_STAGE_ID;
```

This resulted in: "SQL Error: ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "A"."TO_STAGE_ID"
38104. 00000 -  "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: %s"
*Cause:    LHS of UPDATE SET contains the columns referenced in the ON Clause

I can try deleting the rows that require updating and populating them from a staging/temp table, but am interested to see if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the first case is because you are trying to reference the columns using table aliases that are only valid within the scope of the subquery.  You should be able to get around that by aliasing the columns:

```
update 
  (
     select  a.ID, a.FROM_STAGE_ID, a.TO_STAGE_ID a_to_stage_id, b.TO_STAGE_ID b_to_stage_id
       from  STATES a,
             STATES b
      where  a.ID = b.ID and
             a.TO_STAGE_ID = b.FROM_STAGE_ID and
             a.TO_STAGE_ID = 'FIZZBUZZ' and
             a.FROM_STAGE_ID <> b.TO_STAGE_ID and
             a.CODE = b.CODE
   )
   set a_to_stage_id = b_to_stage_id
```

This still may not work - it depends on whether the join preserves the key of the original table.

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. "SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly."